# BIOS settings: always enable onboard graphics

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, bios, gpu

My GPU (GTX 760) has 4 Display Outputs. My mainboard Gigabyte GA-AB350M-Gaming 3 has 3 Display Outputs. I'm trying to connect 7 monitors to the whole System. However the on board GPU get's disabled once you Plug in a GPU. So I learned I should enable the onboard graphics in the BIOS settings. However i do not see any graphic related settings in my Bios. This is a detailed overview of my Bios.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CLXfZeGGyY

How can I enable the onboard graphics?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: alright, I've tried my best

Comment: If your MB automatically disables the onboard graphics when it detects the addon card there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: If that's true I have to trash my mainboard and get a new one. Tell me it aint true

Answer (score 1):

The "Integrated Graphics" option is at the top of the "chipset" page. On my (different) gigabyte board, the options are "auto, enable, and disable." Unfortunately, the manual for your motherboard says the options are "auto" or "disable."

Also according to the manual, the setting will not appear in the menu if your CPU does not have integrated graphics.